# Dropdown with prototype.js in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, prototypejs

I had trouble with this script: http://loki.timon.com.ua/select/
In IE8: all works great - dropdowns work, cloned dropdowns work.
In IE7: drop downs dont work.
In IE8 with IE7mode: first dropdown work normally, cloned - not.

People, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.
Just replace

```
onclick="changeMessengerType(this);"
```

CHANGES TO

```
onclick="changeMessengerType($(this));"
```

And

```
liselected.update(li.innerHTML);
```

TO

```
$(liselected).update(li.innerHTML);
```

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I have IE7 at work... so for me the script does not work as is... although it does work fine in FF3.5+

When fiddling with it locally... I got it to work by changing the following lines....

```
<dl class="selectboxs" style="width:74px;" onclick="this.down('dd').toggle()">
```

**CHANGES TO**

```
<dl class="selectboxs" style="width:74px;" onclick="$(this).down('dd').toggle()">
```

Note the $ which is what makes it a prototype object. This is odd since prototype usually wraps elements automatically, but that is what i got..

I also changed the function to add the $() around id.. same reason.. similarly perplexed.

```
function addMessenger(id)
{
    $(id).insert({after:'<div>' + $(id).innerHTML + '</div>'});
    return false;
}
```

However I've never used prototype calls from inline js, so maybe something to do with that? Perhaps the JS/prototype experts can help?

Comment: Java Drinker, after changing 'this' to '$(this)' dropdown began open, but value of dropdown dont changed.